# auto login as guest without gdm3 with systemd ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, login, lxde, autologin

I Installed Ubuntu 18.04 and removed gdm3 package.

Now on startup I get LXDE GUI with my default admin user logged in (the one created after initial OS setup with sudo capabilities).
I wish to create a guest user which not belongs to sudo group and make the system login automatically with that user to restrict guest actions. In case of need we can logout and login as the admin.

I don't know if its done in systemd or LXDE settings and how to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to perform that by editing the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and specify the default user.